# Testnet Bitcoin wallet: which script in hash addresses?

Tags: wallet, address, testnet, p2sh

Why does the Testnet Wallet create receiving addresses in the form of script hash addresses ([prefix](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes) *2*) instead of "plain" *m/n*-prefixed addresses? Is there any security reason? And, which script does it hash? I was assuming, from [BIP.16](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki), a single-signature case:

> scriptPubKey: OP_HASH160 [20-byte-hash of {[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG} ]
> OP_EQUAL

But I was not able to obtain the same script hash (of course I know the private key). I tried the following steps:

> $ echo [*02b6d...public key...47f89*] checksig > script
>
> $ bx script-encode < script | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160
>
> *046f...fb3*
>
> $ echo hash160 [*046f...fb3*] equal > script2
>
> $ bx script-encode < script2 | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | bx base58check-encode --version 196
>
> *2NxxxexxxxxL*

(I had expected to get the same result built by the wallet, but they were different).

Please note that I know for sure both the private and public keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What're seeing is a P2SH embedded Segwit address.

It contains the hash of the script `OP_0 [20-byte hash160 of compressed pubkey]`.

You can configure Bitcoin Core to instead produce legacy P2PKH addresses (start with `-addresstype=legacy`). You can also make it construct Bech32 (BIP173) addresses using `-addresstype=bech32`, which represent the `OP_0 [20-byte hash160 of compressed pubkey]` script directly. These are cheaper to spend, but not all software supports sending to them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pieter-wuille, I confirm it is a P2SH embedded Segwit address:

```
$ echo '0 [a01..pukbKeyHash..e8e]' | bx script-to-address -v  196
2Mu..xxxx..r
```

Or:

```
$ echo '0 [a01..pukbKeyHash..e8e]' > script3
$ bx script-encode < script3 | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | bx base58check-encode --version 196
2Mu..xxxx..r
```

Which is the address I was looking for.